# Text Background color overshoots Frame at top and bottom

Tags: graphics, frame, background

```
$Version
```

> "12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"

---

To demonstrate the spill over:

```
t = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 3, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

Graphics[{
  Rectangle[{0.65, 1.65}, {1.35, 2.3}],
  Text[Framed[Grid@t, FrameMargins -> Medium], {1, 2}, 
   Background -> White]
  }
 , Frame -> True
 , PlotRange -> {{0.5, 1.5}, {1.5, 2.5}}]
```

[image]

I was trying to create a quick shadow using two framed text objects with different backgrounds and a slight offset when I encountered this problem. Perhaps this has already been resolved in newer versions.

---

**EDIT** to include the simplified code for creating the shadow.

```
Graphics[{
  Text[Framed@Grid@t, {1.04, 1.96}, Background -> Black],
  Text[Framed[Grid@t, FrameMargins -> Medium], {1, 2}, 
   Background -> White]
  }
 , Frame -> True
 , PlotRange -> {{0.5, 1.5}, {1.5, 2.5}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Regarding your comment [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/112266): that's on purpose. The links don't work for me either, but the images do, and they need to have [some form of attribution](/help/referencing).

Comment: When I review an edit with links, I click on all links one by one to ensure accessibility. I didn't check the links in the original post but only for the new edits @Glorfindel. If this has caused an inconvenience, then please accept my apologies.

Comment: No problem, thanks for thoroughly reviewing :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `ImageMargins` will help.

```
t = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 3, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

Graphics[{Rectangle[{0.65, 1.65}, {1.35, 2.3}], 
  Text[Framed[Grid@t, FrameMargins -> Medium, 
    ImageMargins -> {{1, 2}, {1, 1}}], {1, 2}, Background -> White]}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0.5, 1.5}, {1.5, 2.5}}, 
 ImageSize -> 130]
```

Comment: I did play around with options for `Framed` but `Text` is easier to integrate with `Graphics`. Please see my edit as to what I was trying to do. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Not sure what you are actually are trying to achieve, but I think what Chris suggest with the setting `ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {-1, -1}}` might probably do what you are looking for. Problem is that I am not sure whether this will be a general solution or the exact values to use need to be adjusted to the size, resolution, aspect ratio of the plot or even other circumstances of the rendering environment...